# "CASE" statement within "WHERE" clause in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I am working with a query which contains "CASE" statement within "WHERE" clause. But SQL Server 2008 is giving some errors while executing it. Can anyone please help me with the correct query? Here is the query:

```
SELECT
    tl.storenum 'Store #', 
    co.ccnum 'FuelFirst Card #', 
    co.dtentered 'Date Entered',
    CASE st.reasonid 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Active' 
   WHEN 2 THEN 'Not Active' 
   WHEN 0 THEN st.ccstatustypename 
   ELSE 'Unknown' 
    END 'Status',
    CASE st.ccstatustypename 
        WHEN 'Active' THEN ' ' 
   WHEN 'Not Active' THEN ' ' 
   ELSE st.ccstatustypename 
    END 'Reason',
    UPPER(REPLACE(REPLACE(co.personentered,'RT\\\\',''),'RACETRAC\\\\','')) 'Person Entered',
    co.comments 'Comments or Notes'
FROM 
    comments co
    INNER JOIN cards cc ON co.ccnum=cc.ccnum
    INNER JOIN customerinfo ci ON cc.customerinfoid=ci.customerinfoid
    INNER JOIN ccstatustype st ON st.ccstatustypeid=cc.ccstatustypeid
    INNER JOIN customerstatus cs ON cs.customerstatuscd=ci.customerstatuscd
    INNER JOIN transactionlog tl ON tl.transactionlogid=co.transactionlogid
    LEFT JOIN stores s ON s.StoreNum = tl.StoreNum
WHERE 
    CASE LEN('TestPerson')
        WHEN 0 THEN co.personentered  = co.personentered
   ELSE co.personentered LIKE '%TestPerson'
    END 
    AND cc.ccnum = CASE LEN('TestFFNum')
        WHEN 0 THEN cc.ccnum 
   ELSE 'TestFFNum' 
    END 
    AND CASE LEN('2011-01-09 11:56:29.327') 
        WHEN 0 THEN co.DTEntered = co.DTEntered 
   ELSE 
       CASE LEN('2012-01-09 11:56:29.327') 
           WHEN 0 THEN co.DTEntered >= '2011-01-09 11:56:29.327' 
      ELSE co.DTEntered BETWEEN '2011-01-09 11:56:29.327' AND '2012-01-09 11:56:29.327' 
       END 
    END
    AND tl.storenum < 699 
ORDER BY tl.StoreNum
```

Comment: Case _expression_, not statement... (The case expression returns a value. The case statement is used in stored procedures for conditional execution of code.)

Answer (score 259):

First off, the `CASE` statement must be *part* of the expression, not the expression itself.

In other words, you can have:

```
WHERE co.DTEntered = CASE 
                          WHEN LEN('blah') = 0 
                               THEN co.DTEntered 
                          ELSE '2011-01-01' 
                     END
```

But it won't work the way you have written them eg:

```
WHERE 
    CASE LEN('TestPerson')
        WHEN 0 THEN co.personentered  = co.personentered
   ELSE co.personentered LIKE '%TestPerson'
    END
```

You may have better luck using combined OR statements like this:

```
WHERE (
        (LEN('TestPerson') = 0 
             AND co.personentered = co.personentered
        ) 
        OR 
        (LEN('TestPerson') <> 0 
             AND co.personentered LIKE '%TestPerson')
      )
```

Although, either way I'm not sure how great of a query plan you'll get. These types of shenanigans in a `WHERE` clause will often prevent the query optimizer from utilizing indexes.

Comment: WHEN 0 THEN co.personentered  = co.personentered, Here this check co.personentered  = co.personentered is not needed as it will always return true and length value will always be positive. So, making LEN('TestPerson') > 0 will reduce the range needed to be compared

Comment: how to check `co.personentered` is not null, in option 1 and 2. Now 3 rd option is enough. But I want to know that...!!

Comment: i tried so far `where 
case c
 when 1 then (DescriptionCode is null) 
 else descriptioncode is not null 
end`, but i shows the error like `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'is'.`

Answer (score 23):

Try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM emp_master 
WHERE emp_last_name= 
CASE emp_first_name 
 WHEN 'test'    THEN 'test' 
 WHEN 'Mr name' THEN 'name'
END
```

Answer (score 16):

This should solve your problem for the time being but I must remind you it isn't a good approach :

```
WHERE 
            CASE LEN('TestPerson')
                WHEN 0 THEN 
                        CASE WHEN co.personentered  = co.personentered THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                ELSE 
                        CASE WHEN co.personentered LIKE '%TestPerson' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            END = 1
        AND cc.ccnum = CASE LEN('TestFFNum')
                            WHEN 0 THEN cc.ccnum 
                            ELSE 'TestFFNum' 
                       END 
        AND CASE LEN('2011-01-09 11:56:29.327') 
                WHEN 0 THEN CASE WHEN co.DTEntered = co.DTEntered THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
                ELSE 
                    CASE LEN('2012-01-09 11:56:29.327') 
                        WHEN 0 THEN 
                            CASE WHEN co.DTEntered >= '2011-01-09 11:56:29.327' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
                        ELSE 
                            CASE WHEN co.DTEntered BETWEEN '2011-01-09 11:56:29.327' 
                                                        AND '2012-01-09 11:56:29.327' 
                                                     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                    END
            END = 1
        AND tl.storenum < 699
```

Answer (score 8):

I think that the beginning of your query should look like that:

```
SELECT
    tl.storenum [Store #], 
    co.ccnum [FuelFirst Card #], 
    co.dtentered [Date Entered],
    CASE st.reasonid 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Active' 
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Not Active' 
        WHEN 0 THEN st.ccstatustypename 
        ELSE 'Unknown' 
    END [Status],
    CASE st.ccstatustypename 
        WHEN 'Active' THEN ' ' 
        WHEN 'Not Active' THEN ' ' 
        ELSE st.ccstatustypename 
        END [Reason],
    UPPER(REPLACE(REPLACE(co.personentered,'RT\\\\',''),'RACETRAC\\\\','')) [Person Entered],
    co.comments [Comments or Notes]
FROM comments co
    INNER JOIN cards cc ON co.ccnum=cc.ccnum
    INNER JOIN customerinfo ci ON cc.customerinfoid=ci.customerinfoid
    INNER JOIN ccstatustype st ON st.ccstatustypeid=cc.ccstatustypeid
    INNER JOIN customerstatus cs ON cs.customerstatuscd=ci.customerstatuscd
    INNER JOIN transactionlog tl ON tl.transactionlogid=co.transactionlogid
    LEFT JOIN stores s ON s.StoreNum = tl.StoreNum
WHERE 
    CASE 
      WHEN (LEN([TestPerson]) = 0 AND co.personentered  = co.personentered) OR (LEN([TestPerson]) <> 0 AND co.personentered LIKE '%'+TestPerson) THEN 1
      ELSE 0
      END = 1
    AND
```

**BUT**

what is in the tail is completely not understandable

Answer (score 4):

There `WHERE` part could be written like this:

```
WHERE 
 (LEN('TestPerson') <> 0 OR co.personentered  = co.personentered) AND
 (LEN('TestPerson') = 0 OR co.personentered LIKE '%TestPerson') AND
 (cc.ccnum = CASE LEN('TestFFNum')
                WHEN 0 THEN cc.ccnum 
                ELSE 'TestFFNum' 
              END ) AND
 (LEN('2011-01-09 11:56:29.327') <> 0 OR co.DTEntered = co.DTEntered ) AND
 ((LEN('2011-01-09 11:56:29.327') = 0 AND LEN('2012-01-09 11:56:29.327') <> 0) OR co.DTEntered >= '2011-01-09 11:56:29.327'  ) AND
 ((LEN('2011-01-09 11:56:29.327') = 0 AND LEN('2012-01-09 11:56:29.327') = 0) OR co.DTEntered BETWEEN '2011-01-09 11:56:29.327' AND '2012-01-09 11:56:29.327'  ) AND 
 tl.storenum < 699
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 select 
d.DISTNAME,e.BLKNAME,a.childid,a.studyingclass 
from Tbl_AdmissionRegister a
inner join District_master b on a.Schooid=b.Schooid
where 
case when len('3601')=4   then c.distcd 
           when len('3601')=6   then c.blkcd  
           when len('3601')=11  then c.schcd   end = '3601'
```

Comment: Please provide more information as to why your answer helps solve the original question. Posting just code can be a little vague for users with the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for this question, actually I am looking for something else which is in below query. this may helps someone.

```
      SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN OPPORTUNITY='' THEN '(BLANK)' ELSE OPPORTUNITY END
  AS OPP,LEN(OPPORTUNITY) FROM [DBO].[TBL]
```

above query is to fill in dropdown which blank values shows as "(blank)". Also if we pass this value into sql where clause to get blank values with other values I don't know how to handle that. And finally came up with below solution this may helps to somebody.

here it is ,

```
 DECLARE @OPP TABLE (OPP VARCHAR(100))
  INSERT INTO @OPP VALUES('(BLANK)'),('UNFUNDED'),('FUNDED/NOT COMMITTED')
SELECT DISTINCT [OPPORTUNITY]
FROM [DBO].[TBL]   WHERE    (  CASE WHEN   OPPORTUNITY ='' THEN '(BLANK)' ELSE OPPORTUNITY END IN (SELECT OPP FROM @OPP))
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try like below eg. to show only Outbound Shipments

```
   SELECT shp_awb_no,shpr_ctry_cd, recvr_ctry_cd,
     CASE WHEN shpr_ctry_cd = record_ctry_cd 
     THEN "O" 
     ELSE "I" 
      END AS route
     FROM shipment_details
    WHERE record_ctry_cd = "JP"
      AND "O" = CASE WHEN shpr_ctry_cd = record_ctry_cd 
                THEN "O" 
                ELSE "I" 
                 END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CASE LEN('TestPerson')
    WHEN 0 THEN co.personentered  = co.personentered ELSE co.personentered LIKE '%TestPerson'
```

Try the following:

```
... and ( 
    (LEN('TestPerson') = 0 and co.personentered  = co.personentered) or
    (LEN('TestPerson') <> 0 and co.personentered LIKE '%TestPerson') ) and ...
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution

```
AND CLI.PE_NOM Like '%' + ISNULL(@NomClient, CLI.PE_NOM) + '%'
```

Regads 
Davy

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
declare @v int=A
select * from Table_Name where XYZ=202 
and 
dbkey=(case @v  when A then 'Some Value 1'
else 'Some Value 2'
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using somtehing like that to filter users according to needle as string and a dropdown in the UI

```
where 
        u.username like '%' + isnull(@needle, '') + '%'
    and 1 =
    (
        case 
            when @status = 0            then 1 -- All in uu
            when @status = u.statusid   then 1 -- Special status 
            else 0 -- otherwise reject
        end
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select TUM1.userid,TUM1.first_name + ' ' +TUM1.last_name as NAME,tum1.Business_Title,TUM1.manager_id,tum2.First_Name + ' ' + tum2.Last_Name as [MANAGER NAME],TUM1.project,TUM1.project_code,TUM1.rcc_code,TUM1.department,TCM.Company_Name,
case 
when tum1.Gender_ID=1 then 'male' 
else 'female' 
end 'GENDER'
,tum1.Band as BAND,
case when tum1.Inactive=0 then 'STILL IN COMPANY'
else 'LEFT COMPANY' 
end 'ACTIVE/INACTIVE'
from tbl_user_master TUM1
join tbl_Company_Master TCM on TCM.Company_Code=TUM1.Company_Code 
join tbl_User_Master TUM2 on TUM1.Manager_ID=TUM2.UserID 
where tum1.UserID in ('54545414')
```

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT * from TABLE 
              WHERE 1 = CASE when TABLE.col = 100 then 1 
                     when TABLE.col = 200 then 2 else 3 END 
                  and TABLE.col2 = 'myname';
```

Use in this way.