# Case When in SQL procedure

Tags: sql, case

I'm trying to use a case when in a sql procedure.

What i want is that when the variable @ID_ETAPA is 6 the where is a little diferent. But i'm getting multiple erros.
Incorrect syntax near =
And
Incorrect syntax near ELSE
Someone knows what i'm missing?

```
WHERE CASE 
      WHEN @ID_ETAPA=6 THEN 
        SS.ID_STATUSSOLICITACAO = 1 -- PENDENTES
            AND SS.Id_etapa = @ID_ETAPA 
        Else
            SS.ID_STATUSSOLICITACAO = 1 -- PENDENTES
   END
```

---

THE full select with error in the where clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CF.NOM_FILIAL,
        SS.COD_SOLICITACAO,
        SS.COD_GTV,
        SS.SEQ_GTV,
        SS.COD_SERIEGTV,
        ST.DES_TPSERVICO,
        SSI.DES_SISTEMAANALISE,
        SSI.ID_SISTEMAANALISE,
        SM.DES_MOTIVOSOLICITACAO,
        SE.DES_ETAPA,
        SS.ID_ETAPA,
        SST.DES_STATUSSOLICITACAO,
        CFSOLICITANTE.NOM_FUNC      AS NOM_SOLICITANTE,
        CFSUCESSOR.NOM_FUNC     AS NOM_SUCESSOR,
        CFOPERADOR.NOM_FUNC     AS NOM_OPERADOR,
        SS.DES_DETALHAMENTOGTV,
        SA.ID_GRUPOACESSO

INTO #DADOS

FROM SSE_SOLICITACAO SS

INNER JOIN COR_FILIAL CF
ON  CF.COD_REGIONAL     = SS.COD_REGIONAL
    AND CF.COD_FILIAL   = SS.COD_FILIAL

INNER JOIN SSE_TPSERVICO ST
ON  ST.ID_TPSERVICO = SS.ID_TPSERVICO

INNER JOIN SSE_SISTEMAANALISE SSI
ON  SSI.ID_SISTEMAANALISE = SS.ID_SISTEMAANALISE

INNER JOIN SSE_MOTIVOSOLICITACAO SM
ON  SM.ID_MOTIVOSOLICITACAO = SS.ID_MOTIVOSOLICITACAO

INNER JOIN SSE_ETAPA SE
ON  SE.ID_ETAPA = SS.ID_ETAPA

INNER JOIN SSE_STATUSSOLICITACAO SST
ON  SST.ID_STATUSSOLICITACAO = SS.ID_STATUSSOLICITACAO

INNER JOIN COR_FUNCIONARIO CFSOLICITANTE
ON  CFSOLICITANTE.COD_FUNC = SS.COD_FUNCSOLICITANTE

INNER JOIN SSE_ACESSO SA
ON  SA.COD_FUNCSOLICITANTE = SS.COD_FUNCSOLICITANTE

LEFT JOIN COR_FUNCIONARIO CFSUCESSOR
ON  CFSUCESSOR.COD_FUNC = SS.COD_FUNCSUCESSOR

LEFT JOIN COR_FUNCIONARIO CFOPERADOR
ON  CFOPERADOR.COD_FUNC = SS.COD_FUNCOPERADOR

WHERE SS.ID_STATUSSOLICITACAO = CASE 
      WHEN @ID_ETAPA=6 THEN 
        SS.ID_STATUSSOLICITACAO = 1 -- PENDENTES
            AND SS.Id_etapa = @ID_ETAPA 
        Else
            SS.ID_STATUSSOLICITACAO = 1 -- PENDENTES
   END

ORDER BY SS.COD_SOLICITACAO
```

Comment: The errors continues in the same two places.

Comment: Might be purple's answer will work becausewher condition need operand in condition....

Answer (score 0):

The `CASE` statement must be part of the `WHERE` statement. Try:

```
WHERE SS.ID_STATUSSOLICITACAO = CASE 
      WHEN @ID_ETAPA=6 THEN 
        SS.ID_STATUSSOLICITACAO = 1 -- PENDENTES
            AND SS.Id_etapa = @ID_ETAPA 
        Else
            SS.ID_STATUSSOLICITACAO = 1 -- PENDENTES
   END
```

See this post for more information: ["CASE" statement within "WHERE" clause in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785209/case-statement-within-where-clause-in-sql-server-2008)

**EDIT**

Try taking `SS.ID_STATUSSOLICITACAO = 1` out of the `CASE` expression and placing it afterwards:

```
WHERE SS.Id_etapa = 
    CASE WHEN @ID_ETAPA=6 THEN @ID_ETAPA 
        ELSE 0 --- What you use for this value depends on what other values are possible for the @ID_ETAPA variable of course
    END
AND SS.ID_STATUSSOLICITACAO = 1
```

Comment: I'm still getting the errors in the "=" and in the "Else".Both syntax erros.

Comment: Can you provide the SELECT statement used right before the WHERE clause?

Comment: I updated the answer, but it's important to consider how many different values are possible for your @ID_ETAPA variable. I used "ELSE 0" as a placeholder, but you will want to change it to fit your needs.