# How to use CASE statement when to local variables for multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

on basis of local variable value I want to make condition on a particular column in select statement.

---

```
declare @str VARCHAR(50)='ProjectCostAll'

SELECT pm.intProjectID,pm.strProjectName,im.intInvID,im.strInvNo 
FROM dbo.tblProjectMaster PM
LEFT JOIN dbo.tblInvoiceDetails ID ON id.intProjectID=pm.intProjectID
LEFT JOIN dbo.tblInvoiceMaster IM ON im.intInvID=id.intInvID
WHERE CASE 
    WHEN @str ='ProjectCostInv' THEN 
        ISNULL(IM.intInvID,0) <> 0
    WHEN @str ='ProjectCostNotInv' THEN 
        ISNULL(IM.intInvID,0) = 0
    ELSE
        ISNULL(IM.intInvID,0) >= 0
    end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["CASE" statement within "WHERE" clause in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785209/case-statement-within-where-clause-in-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE (@str = 'ProjectCostInv' AND IM.intInvID <> 0)
    OR (@str = 'ProjectCostNotInv' AND ISNULL(IM.intInvID,0) = 0)
    OR (@str not in ('ProjectCostInv', 'ProjectCostNotInv') AND ISNULL(IM.intInvID,0) >= 0)
```

but the overall approach is bad for performance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't eval the meaning of your case result but out of this 
if you want see  the result in select you should use the case in select  not in where

```
SELECT pm.intProjectID,pm.strProjectName,im.intInvID,im.strInvNo,
    CASE 
        WHEN @str ='ProjectCostInv' THEN '<> 0'
        WHEN @str ='ProjectCostNotInv' THEN '0'
        ELSE '>= 0'
        end my_result 
FROM dbo.tblProjectMaster PM
LEFT  JOIN dbo.tblInvoiceDetails ID ON id.intProjectID=pm.intProjectID
left JOIN dbo.tblInvoiceMaster IM ON im.intInvID=id.intInvID
```