# Case expression failing

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to run the SQL using a `case` expression but seems there is an syntax error

```
SELECT
    MAX(date) AS maxdate,
    MIN(date) AS mindate, 
    id
WHERE 
    (iSkid = 1)

CASE 
   WHEN PageList = 0
      THEN
         AND (startdate <= DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, GetDate()), 0)) 
         AND (enddate >= DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, GetDate()), 0)) 
END
GROUP BY 
    id, maxdate, mindate
```

Errors I get:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 95
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.

tried this way too

```
select max(date) as maxdate,min(date) as mindate, id



CASE WHEN
        PageList = 0
    THEN
        WHERE (iSkid = 1) AND (startdate <= DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, GetDate()), 0)) 
        AND (enddate >= DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, GetDate()), 0)) 
ELSE 
WHERE (iSkid = 1)
    END
GROUP BY 
    id,maxdate,mindate  

    Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 95
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.
```

but something is messed up, and not sure what. any clue?

Comment: In the second example, you are missing a comma before the `case`.  You have a bunch of other problems with the query.  I would recommend that you delete this question.  Then ask a new question, explain the logic you want to implement and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["CASE" statement within "WHERE" clause in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785209/case-statement-within-where-clause-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: better to change your question as you have not written your query in proper way. so explain the problem and sample data with screenshot or so.

Comment: you've mixed CASE and WHERE in an incorrect way, CASE can be used to select a value to apply to WHERE, but not in that way

Comment: Since you need to group by id, the group by should only be GROUP BY maxdate, mindate.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `CASE` to conditionally insert clauses or return partial expressions.

Your first example is the logical equivalent of something like `1 IF(something, + 2, - 1)`, which is fairly obviously invalid, and not something you'd probably ever right. The more common, valid expression of that would be `1 + IF(something, 2, -1)`.

CASE returns values, not expressions (neither full nor partial ones) and not clauses. `AND something` is a partial expression, but `something` should evaluate to a value, as would `something AND somethingelse`. So, while `CASE WHEN x THEN AND something ....` doesn't make sense, something like `AND CASE WHEN x THEN something ...` does. Similarly, `CASE WHEN x THEN WHERE somthing ....` is incorrectly formed; `WHERE CASE WHEN x THEN something ....` is the correct form.

tldr: Your *conditions** in first one were close to correct; you just needed the first `AND` before the `CASE`.... and to determine the truth value that the CASE should return when `PageList = 0` is false. *(* a `GROUP BY` including aggregate results is nonsense too.)*

Answer (score 0):

I think your intention is this:

```
WHERE 
    (iSkid = 1)
    OR
         (PageList = 0
         AND (startdate <= DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, GetDate()), 0)) 
         AND (enddate >= DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, GetDate()), 0)) 
         )
```