# I have a SQL Server 2012 sql query that takes a parameter: @Region There's a WHERE clause that I want to set its value based on the @Region value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server 2012 query that takes a parameter `@Region`. There's a `WHERE` clause that I want to set its value based on the `@Region` value. Below is the code I was trying to use

```sql
case 
    when @Region = 'SW' 
       then Transact.busloc_id in (3, 7, 11)
       else Transact.busloc_id in (1, 5, 7)
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["CASE" statement within "WHERE" clause in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785209/case-statement-within-where-clause-in-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to set a variable's value involving a CASE statement in SQL has the following syntax:

```
SET @Variable = CASE WHEN [condition] THEN [scalar_value] ELSE [scalar_value] END
```

In your SQL you have conditions where scalar values should be.  Without further information on what you're trying to achieve with the IN clauses I can't provide more of an answer, however you can [go here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for more information on the syntax of a CASE statement.

Answer (score 2):

In a `where` clause, you want logic like:

```
where ( @Region = 'SW' and Transact.busloc_id IN (3, 7, 11) ) or
      ( @Region <> 'SW' and Transact.busloc_id IN (1, 5, 7) )
```

No `case` expression is necessary.

Note:  This assumes that `@region` is not `NULL`.  That can easily be handled.

Comment: This worked great !! Now that I look at think I was overthinking it . THANKS!!

Comment: @ErnieSal . . . I don't understand why you accepted an answer that is about setting a parameter rather than handling logic in the `where` clause.