# Where case statement depending on value

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

Getting a parse error when it hits one side of the case statement

I tried using None as the variable I passed in, trying passing in 0, various strings, editing how the case statement reads in sql.

ex
facility = None
When {facility} is Null then 1=1

```
%python

#facility = ("ABC", "DEF", "IJK")
facility = ("None")

facility_counts = spark.sql(f'''

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM database
WHERE CASE
WHEN '{facility}' = 'None' THEN 1=1
ELSE facility <>  not in {facility} END

''')

facility_counts.display()
```

```
ParseException: 
mismatched input 'WHEN' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}(line 5, pos 0)

== SQL ==


SELECT COUNT(*) FROM database
WHERE CASE
WHEN 'None' = 'None' THEN 1=1
^^^
ELSE facility <>  not in None END
```

Comment: `CASE WHEN` can't be used in a `WHERE` clause to choose between multiple conditions that way. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785209/case-statement-within-where-clause-in-sql-server-2008 (which is about SQL Server, but the principle is the same).

Comment: For one thing, you don't have a semicolon at the end of the case...

Comment: Could you clarify what behavior you are trying to achieve with your CASE statement?  Are you actually looking to get a separate count for each facility in the collection, or the sum of counts for all facilities in the collection? Is 'None' an expected value in the "facility" column? Or do you mean the Python singleton value `None` as opposed to a the string 'None` inside of a collection?  If the value is None are you expecting a 1 instead of 0?
Also, using f-strings to create SQL queries is generally a bad idea as it can lead to SQL injection if the interpolated value is user-entered.

Answer (score 0):

The parse error you're encountering is due to incorrect SQL syntax. The CASE statement in SQL is used to perform conditional logic and should return a value, not be used directly in a WHERE clause, see [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp) for more information.